# Not understanding concretely the Wikipedia or text definition of "Subobject classifier"

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory, diagram-chasing

I have **two** major questions.

In the following diagrams, only some of the arrows make sense to me or are explained. Others I have never seen and are not brought up in any of the webpages or books that I have seen.

We are working within the ambient category $\mathrm{Set}$.

$\underline{1}$ denotes the singleton set.

Rather than stating which parts of the diagram commute or using a $\checkmark$ symbol, we will use coloring: Any red or blue path may commute with a black path (and will count as a red/blue path still). However, no red path may commute with a blue path.

**(1)**

I know that the arrow $\underline{1} \xrightarrow{\quad a \quad} A$ categorizes the notion that $a \in A$.

Completely unanswered in my texts is what the arrow $A \xrightarrow{\quad ?\quad} \underline{1}$ is intended to mean. What does this arrow mean in $\mathrm{Set}$? Why would it even *need* to be here?

I don't want any tired recital of "pullbacks" or "spans" or any other category theory jargon that I can already see on wikipedia, I want to know what sort of concrete mapping this is meant to be in set theory, why it needs to be here for this particular instance, and not what it is in terms of abstract nonsense.

**(2)**

I think that I know what a monic arrow (also called a monomorphism) is. This is an arrow $A \xrightarrow{\quad j \quad} X$ where $j(a) = j(a') \Longrightarrow a = a'$.

The internal structure of $\underline{2}$ can be given in the diagram:

[image]

Let's look at set $S = \{\alpha, \beta\}$ and subset $A = \{\alpha \}$. For this toy example, I want every membership to be explicitly categorized. Per my rules, would this be the correct diagram that gives "all" the information?

[image]

Then can we state by reading the arrows off the diagram that

$\chi_A (\alpha) = \chi_A (j (\alpha)) = \mathrm{True}$

Comment: (1) Isn't it just the constant function?

Comment: @Randall Could you give a link for what you're referring to? I had a feeling that it was something minor and easy from set theory. I'll read whatever link you send.

Comment: It's just the constant function, there's nothing more to say about it. $1$ is a singleton so every set $A$ admits a unique function $A \to 1$, which is the constant function with constant value the unique element of $1$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Is there any reason why it needs to be drawn out in the diagram, especially if set memberships (which naively seem more useful to draw out) are usually not drawn? Other than to suggest that we might be dealing with a pullback of the cone $2^\rhd$? I would also suppose then that this arrow commutes with any member of $A$, yes?

Comment: @Nate: the point of that arrow is that the diagram is supposed to be a pullback, yes.

Comment: Thanks you two. In that case, say that I just want to diagram some function and I want to say that it operates on some subset $A \subseteq X$. No need then to draw that arrow if I care not about it being a pullback? I should emphasize I'm an engineer and I'm drawn right now to category theory as more of an organizational tool than anything else.

Comment: In notation $\underline{1} \xrightarrow{\quad a \quad} A$ is not $a$ a map? [not an element of $A$]

Comment: @DanielSchepler Yeah that's a screw up on my part. Editing my question to delete that

Comment: @coffeemath In the books I've read the arrow $\underline{1}$ is treated as a unique object (set) and any arrows of it to any other objects (sets) define a membership of that set. For the diagrams that I draw out I often like to draw the membership arrows for the purposes of self-teaching and making sure I understand things concretely. It makes things very easy to read, since you can just read the arrows "off the diagram", i.e. $f(x)$ is directly extractable from $\underline{1} \xrightarrow{\quad x \quad} X \xrightarrow{\quad f \quad} Y$

Comment: I think the "$?$" is a typo - I've always seen it as "$!$," which is the standard indicator that (as in this case) there is only one morphism with the given domain and codomain.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Haha, that was just me indicating that I had no idea what it was meant to be. I think I've seen the "$!$" indicator in Spivak's book, but I forgot about it.

Comment: I can't tell if the question has already been answered for you or not